# What are the possible properties of CSS that can fetch from other url?

Tags: html, css, url

I want to list down all the CSS properties that can feth there value from external resources.
e.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    background: #ffffff url("http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_tree.png") no-repeat right top;
    margin-right: 200px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Hello World!</h1>
<p>Now the background image is only shown once, and it is also positioned away from the text.</p>
<p>In this example we have also added a margin on the right side, so that the background image will not disturb the text.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Like in the above example "background" fetches its resource from other URL.
What are other CSS properties like above, I have listed some of them below:

```
background-image
list-style-image
content
border-image-source
```

Comment: `::before` is a pseudo-element. Are you trying to refer to `content` property used inside it?

Comment: @ManojKumar Yes Manoj, you are right. content property.

Comment: Some of the properties that I can list out are:

[**@font-face src**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face)
and 
[**mask**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask)

Answer (score 1):

In CSS 2.1, the full list of properties which accept an [`<uri>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#uri) value is

- [`background`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/colors.html#propdef-background) (shorthand for `background-image`)
- [`background-image`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/colors.html#propdef-background-image)
- [`content`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#propdef-content)
- [`cue`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/aural.html#propdef-cue) (shorthand for `cue-after` and `cue-before`)
- [`cue-after`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/aural.html#propdef-cue-after)
- [`cue-before`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/aural.html#propdef-cue-before)
- [`cursor`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/ui.html#propdef-cursor)
- [`list-style`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#propdef-list-style) (shorthand for `list-style-image`)
- [`list-style-image`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#propdef-list-style-image)
- [`play-during`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/aural.html#propdef-play-during)

Note `cue`, `cue-after`, `cue-before` and `play-during` are defined in a non-normative appendix, so UAs are not required to implement them.

Comment: I'd omit all the aural properties - aural styles are not normative and pretty much irrelevant.

Comment: @BoltClock I considered omitting them, but since the asker already knew most of the non-austral ones, I prefer including them. I have added a note, though.